# How to pass command line arguments to sql script from batch file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I have to run a SQL script from a batch file passing arguments to it. How to pass command line arguments to SQL script from a batch file?

I have tried like

**test.bat**:

```
sqlcmd -b -i "%CD%\Target\Rapiscan Systems\MVXR_Database\Ver 2.2\Database backup Job.sql" -V %1 %2
```

I called `test.bat` through createprocess

```
szBatchFileName.Format(".\\Target\\Rapiscan Systems\\MVXR_Database\\Ver 2.2\\%s","test.bat c:\back D:\back" );

if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    chBatchFileName,// Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
{
    char* chError = new char[szError.GetLength()+1];
    _tcscpy(chError, szError);
    MVXRInstallationLog(chError);
    AfxMessageBox(chError);
    return FALSE;
}
//Wait till create process complete the job
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

I have filed to run the script. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a **batch file**, only to call it from C# in the end?? If you're calling it from C# anyway - wouldn't it be much easier to just use the proper ADO.NET calls from C#, instead of going through a batch file??

Comment: `%*` appended to command line of `sqlcmd.exe` is replaced on execution of the batch file by all parameters passed to the batch file. You can see this behavior by executing a batch file with various parameters containing only the command `@echo %*`.